# Show $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin^2{[\pi(x+\frac{1}{x})]}\,\mathrm{d}x$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Show $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin^2{[\pi(x+\frac{1}{x})]}\,\mathrm{d}x$ diverges.

Having trouble doing this.  Can't seem to integrate.  Not sure how to setup a comparison.  Any ideas?

Comment: for large $x$ near an odd multiple of $\frac{1}{2}$, the integrand is basically $1$

Comment: @mathworker21 How exactly is that sufficient to say that the integral diverges?  I'm not too sure what theorem is being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $\sin^2$ is a Lipschitz-continuous function, so for any $x\geq 1$
$$ \left|\sin^2\left(\pi\left(x+\tfrac{1}{x}\right)\right)-\sin^2(\pi x)\right|\leq \frac{\pi}{x}\tag{1}$$
holds. In particular we have
$$ \int_{1}^{N}\sin^2\left(\pi\left(x+\tfrac{1}{x}\right)\right)\,dx = \int_{1}^{N}\sin^2(\pi x)\,dx + O(\log N) \tag{2}$$
but for any $N\in\mathbb{N}^+$ the RHS is $\frac{N-1}{2}+O(\log N)$, which is unbounded as $N\to +\infty$.

Comment: How you get equation $(2)$ and what is $O(\log N)$?

Comment: @helios321: $(1)$ is a consequence of Lipschitz-continuity and $\int_{1}^{N}\frac{dx}{x}=\log N$.

Comment: @helios321: $f=O(g)$ is Landau's notation, it means that the ratio $\left|\frac{f}{g}\right|$ is bounded by an absolute constant.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding the final step, namely concluding that the LHS is unbounded.  If $f=O(g)$ means that $f$ grows no faster than $g$, if we take integrals can't we at most say that $\int f \leq \int g$?

Comment: @helios321: $\int_{1}^{N}\sin^2(\pi x)\,dx$ has been computed exactly. So $\int_{1}^{N}\sin^2(\pi(x+1/x))\,dx$ behaves like a linear function plus a logarithmic perturbation. In particular it is unbounded.

Comment: Just to test my understanding if $\int_{1}^{N}\sin^2(\pi x)\,dx$ was not present in equation (2) and we only had $O(log N)$, taking $N\to \infty$ would the RHS still be unbounded?

Comment: @helios321: if $A(N)=N+O(\log N)$ then $A(N)$ is unbounded, yes.