# If $f>0$ when does $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converge/diverge?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f>0$ when does $I=\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converge/diverge?  In particular:

(1) If $f$ is **not decreasing**, does that imply that $I$ diverges?

(2) If $f$ does not approach $0$ as $x\to\infty$ does that imply $I$ diverges?

EDIT:  For (1) seems answer is no.  I have a follow up question:

Now suppose also that $f$ is periodic and continuous.

(3) If the local maxima are not decreasing as $x\to\infty$, does that imply $I$ diverges?  E.g. the local maxima for $\sin^2(x)$ is always $1$ and diverges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) **yes if** $f$ is **non-decreasing** : since $f(x)\geq f(a)>0$ in particular, so 
$$\int_a^{\infty}f(x) dx \geq \int_a^{\infty}f(a) dx=f(a)\int_a^{\infty} dx=+\infty  $$

**But** you can't know if $f$ is just **not decreasing** : for exemple 
$f(x)= 1_{x\geq1}\frac1{x^2}(2+\cos(x))$ is not decreasing but the integral converge...

(2) no  : you can imagine $f(x)=\exp(-x^2)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{N}^*$ and $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{N}^*$ : 
then $$ \int_a^{\infty}f(x) dx = \int_a^{\infty}\exp(-x^2) dx <\infty $$
but $f$ does not tend to $0$....

(3) : no, you can use the same example I gave in (2)

Comment: Hello I added question (3) in response to (1).  Can you help?

Comment: @helios321 : in fact the exemple that I gave in (2), gives an answer 'no' to (3), since the local maximas are $f(n)=n$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$.

Comment: What's $ \mathbb{N}^*$?

Comment: My real problem has been this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664428/show-int-0-infty-sin2-pix-frac1x-mathrmdx-diverges  I can't get a clear proof on it.  Any ideas?

Comment: @helios321: the positives integers : $1,2,3,4,\dots...$

Comment: @helios321: the idea Lucas gave to you is good : did you achieve first to prove that $\int\sin^2(\pi x)dx$ is divergent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73629/discussion-between-helios321-and-netchaiev).

Answer (score 1):

(1) Yes. With $c:=f(a)>0$, you have $f(x)\ge c$ for all $x$, hence $\int_A^B f(x)\,\mathrm dx\ge c(B-A)$ for all $B>A$, whereas convergence would require this to be $<\epsilon$ if only $A,B\gg 0$.

(2) The integral may still converge. $f$ might have a sequence of "bumps" of fixed positive height, but rapidly decreasing width.

Comment: Not decreasing is not the same as non-decreasing.

Comment: @drhab : Well for "not decreasing", part (2) of this answer answers that too.

Comment: @Max : still, the answer to (1) is no...

Answer (score 1):

Hint on 1):

Note that the function $1_{\mathbb N}$ is not decreasing.

---

**edit**:

If $f$ is continuous and $f(x_0)>0$ for some $x_0$ then for $\epsilon>0$ small enough we have $x\in(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\implies f(x)\geq\frac12 f(x_0)$ so that $\int_{x_0-\epsilon}^{x_0+\epsilon}f(x)\geq\int_{x_0-\epsilon}^{x_0+\epsilon}\frac12f(x_0)\geq\epsilon f(x_0)$.

If moreover it has a period $p$ then we get $\int_{x_0+np-\epsilon}^{x_0+np+\epsilon}f(x)\geq\epsilon f(x_0)$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$.

This leads to $\int_a^{\infty}f(x)dx=+\infty$.

Comment: sorry what is that function?

Comment: It takes value $1$ if $x$ is a natural number, and takes value $0$ otherwise. The indicator function of $\mathbb N\subseteq\mathbb R$.

Comment: Your function is periodic but not continuous correct?  Just wondering.

Comment: That is correct.