# Big O notation: If $f=O(g)$ then $\int f=O(\int g)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Big O notation: If $f=O(g)$ then $\int f=O(\int g)$?

This is a follow up question to [Show $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin^2{[\pi(x+\frac{1}{x})]}\,\mathrm{d}x$ diverges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664428/show-int-0-infty-sin2-pix-frac1x-mathrmdx-diverges) where the above statement is employed.  I'm wondering if anyone can give a justification of the above statement.  It seems to make intuitive sense that if $f$ grows no faster than $g$ then the same should be the case for their integrals.  However I'm not all familiar with big O but by my understanding it suffices to prove that something like $\frac{\int f}{\int g}$ is bounded.  Can anyone provide some kind of rigorous proof or explanation of the statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorem you can use  here :

> If $f$ and $g$ are positive functions such that $f=O(g)$ (at infinity), then
>   1) if $\int_a^{\infty}g(t)dt< \infty$ then $\int_a^{\infty}f(t)dt< \infty$ and $x\mapsto \int_x^{\infty}f(t) dt =O\bigg(x\mapsto \int_x^{\infty}g(t) dt\bigg)\ $ ;
>   2) if $\int_a^{\infty}f(t)dt= \infty$ then $\int_a^{\infty}g(t)dt= \infty$ and $x\mapsto \int_a^xf(t) dt =O\bigg(x\mapsto \int_a^xg(t) dt\bigg)$.

It is the analog of comparison between positive sum $\sum$.

ps : it make nos sense to write $\int f = O(\int g)$, since the $O$ notation is a (local) comparison of functions.

More generally :

> If $f$ and $g$ are positive functions such that $f=O(g)$ (at $b$), then
>   1) if $\int_a^{b}g(t)dt< \infty$ then $\int_a^{b}f(t)dt< \infty$ and $x\mapsto \int_x^{b}f(t) dt =O\bigg(x\mapsto \int_x^{b}g(t) dt\bigg)\ $ ;
>   2) if $\int_a^{b}f(t)dt= \infty$ then $\int_a^{b}g(t)dt= \infty$ and $x\mapsto \int_a^xf(t) dt =O\bigg(x\mapsto \int_a^xg(t) dt\bigg)$.

Comment: What should i change it to?  Can't you have comparison at a point rather than infinity?  your statement seems to only cover infinity cases?

Comment: @helios : You can take any point beside infinity : see edit.

Comment: @helios321 : but in your case you were looking to an integral from $0$ to $\infty$, right?

Comment: Yeh in that question we are going to $\infty$.  In that question, can you tell whether (1) or (2) is being used according to the first part of your answer?

Comment: @helios321 for the question you are interested in you could apply (2) IF the condition $f=0(g)$ were valid (i.e, there exists $N$ and $C$ such that for all $x>N$, $|f(x)|\leq C |g(x)|$ ) ; which is not the case in your question : $\sin^2(\pi (x+\frac1x))$ and $\sin^2(\pi x)$ are "close" near infinity, but since they won't be equal to zero at the same time, cannot verify such a property.